# Choosing a place to fix/replace eyeglass frames

Tags: netherlands

I'm a recent expatriate to the Netherlands (specifically, Amsterdam). My eyeglasses got sort of bent, and I need to try and fix the frame and/or replace it. I went to one shop when this happened to me and they said they were worried they might break because a joint was cracked, so they didn't do much.

So, I'm looking for someplace which would be brave and skilled enough to do delicate work on a potentially-cracked frame joint, but wise enough to not recklessly risk it. At the same time I should probably get a spare frame in case this one really breaks.

I noticed there are optician shop networks, and there are smaller opticians/optometrists, and I'm wondering how to choose. Back home I would go to someone I trust who sold me my current frame - nearly 10 years ago, actually - but here I have no idea. Also, I'm not sure how I can check price ranges for glass frames, since there seems to be so much variety.

Notes:

- In case it matters, the eyeglasses are uni-focal. The frame is by 'REPLAY'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I just started arbitrarily going into optician's shops near where I live. At some point, one of them simply offered to try to bend my frame back into shape, and said he was pretty sure he would not break it. So I let him do that; he didn't charge anything.

Anyway, "just try arbitrarily" may not be a bad answer.

Comment: I heard that free basic repairs to eyeglass frames are quite standard among established opticians, apparently it's some sort of honour code.